# Looking for a free xsd scheme editor

Tags: xml, editor, xsd

I'm looking for a free alternative to all the XML/XSD editors around here (that are relatively expensive--at least for me). I totally fail to find one.

I need it to allow me to edit xsd files to help in writting an xml-based language specification. I need it to be visual to help with the design, making it clear. Other features are less interesting for me.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 10):

Checkout out [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=xsd#xsd). They've got XSD modelling tools which work quite nicely with a graphical representation of the scheme.

Comment: Seems a bit overkill for only xml edition, don't you think?

Comment: I just tried installing those missing plugins ... what a pain!

Comment: I just tried Eclipse this past couple of weeks and after I figured out what was what it really is pretty good. For 2015 and later, you download the data modeling tools (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-modeling-tools/lunasr1) and extract. Run (as admin in windows) and then go into the plugins area and somewhere there will be xml related one. Install it and you can then start creating xsd! From the limited choices I saw available this one works and was pretty easy. The MAIN thing to understand if you follow my instructions is that you MUST create a project to contain your xsd.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [XML pad](http://www.wmhelp.com).

Update:

Changed the link, it seams that they are in transition.

Update 2:

The link is now back on.

Comment: Dead link.  Can you update it please?

Comment: Thx, i changed the link, but it seems that i will have to change that in time because they are moving somewhere

Comment: @RyanShillington the link is back on.

Answer (score 4):

[XML Fox](http://www.xmlfox.com/index.htm) might be what you need.

Comment: I too will vote for XML Fox. It is light weight and portable.

Answer (score 2):

XML Spy 2006 community edition was free. It can still be found on the internet but I don't know if you can still get the free licensekey.

Comment: Same thing with The Liquid XML Studio Community Edition... http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Products/CommunityEditionInformation.aspx

Comment: Download links that don't go to altova still has the 2006 version. I know because I downloded it myself a couple of weeks ago. Unfortunatly I don't have the link available now.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check out the XML Schema editor that comes with Eclipse WTP. Take a look at the blog posting at http://codegears.blogspot.com/2008/03/working-with-schema-files-in-eclipse_3125.html, it has some screenshots to illustrate the use of the visual editor.

HOWEVER - to really understand what's going on, you'll probably need to read the code, no matter how clever the visual editor is.

Comment: I know I'll need to read the code, but I need to get faster than writitng the code myself and having lot of syntax errors...

Answer (score 0):

I personaly find JDeveloper xml related plugins very usefull.